# Combining a new set of JavaScript files into a Rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a fully functional, existing Rails app. A friend of mine just built a few new front-end pages for me, but he just built them in html, with some JavaScript files.

Adding in the HTML has been easy, but I cannot figure out how to get the corresponding JavaScript files working.

I have imported all the JavaScript files into the app/assets/javascripts folders, and added them to the application.js file like this:

`//= require modules/alerts
//= require modules/dropdown`

etc.

But none of the JavaScript shows up - I threw some `console.log` lines in them just to test, but the lines never show. What else do I need to do to connect these JavaScript files?

Current structure:

app

- assets
- - javascripts
- - - modules
- - - application.js (also inside javascripts folder like modules folder)

I am also getting this alert in console:

`mobile-nav.source.js:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: alerts is not defined
    at mobile-nav.source.js:23`

But just checked the `mobile-nav.js` file and line 23 has nothing about alerts.

I think my error is coming from `modules/init-modules.js` - I am adding in `alerts: alerts` to the var Modules object, and when I do that, it seems to break all the other js. Is there something I need to do first before I can add to this file?

EDIT: Found the issue! Thanks for everyone that helped. There was a variable being declared incorrectly, but the way it was throwing the error made it hard to find.

Comment: What is the folder structure of the javascript files? Update it in the question.

Comment: Just added @Pavan

Comment: Do you have your `javascript_include_tag :application` in the application layout?

Comment: @BrandonCordell Yeah i do - I have old javascript files working, just can't get these new ones I'm importing to connect.

Comment: Do you see any errors in browsers console or server log? If so, update the question with those errors.

Comment: @Pavan just added